# How to find values of nested object properties

Tags: c#, object, reflection

I have a function that will find properties with empty values on an object and set them to null. This works fine. The problem now is that sometimes there is a nested object and I'm not sure how to iterate through that to do the same logic.

```
public static T SetEmptyPropertiesNull<T>(T request, Type type)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        object value = property.GetValue(request, null);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((value ?? string.Empty).ToString()))
            property.SetValue(request, null);
    }

    return request;
}
```

So for example, say I have a Customer object and on that object I have an Address object. The function I have now will find all of the empty values on the Customer object and convert them to null, but it also needs to find all of the values on the nested Address object and convert them to null. This function can be called for different object types and not all object types will have a nested object. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

So this works, but I would really like to accomplish this without having to specify the object type, AddressDto. I would like it to be dynamic and accept any object type.

```
public static T SetEmptyPropertiesNull<T>(T request)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in request.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        object value = property.GetValue(request, null);

        if (value.GetType() == typeof(AddressDto))
            SetEmptyPropertiesNull(value);
        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((value ?? string.Empty).ToString()))
            property.SetValue(request, null);
    }

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Why would you set the properties of an object you afterwards are setting to null? what is the point?

Comment: I'm not setting them initially. I'm receiving them from another process and they may be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, assuming the 'type' parameter is the type of the request parameter, you don't need to pass it.  typeof(T) will give you the type.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
```

Next up, to determine if the property is a class, you can call

```
value.GetType().IsClass
```

So your code might look like this:

```
public static T SetEmptyPropertiesNull<T>(T request)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        object value = property.GetValue(request, null);

        if (value.GetType().IsClass)
            SetEmptyPropertiesNull(value);
        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((value ?? string.Empty).ToString()))
            property.SetValue(request, null);
    }

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `T` resolve to object on the recursive call?  Shouldn't it be changed to not use generics at all and use `request.GetType()` instead of `typeof(T)`?

Comment: Tim, you are right. This approach only works if I use `request.GetType()`. Also `typeof(value).IsClass` won't work for two reasons. One being, `typeof` wont accepts a variable as a type so it won't even compile. If I change that to `value.GetType().IsClass`, it still wont work because some of my properties are strings and strings are type of class....

Comment: Right I said value.GetType() then typed typeof(value).  My bad.  Fixed.  And yes you could do request.GetType() instead of typeof(T).  Either way you do not need to explicitly pass in the type.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mark Saphiro answer I changed a litle bit the code to avoid reference cycles. I save the visited objects in a `HashSet` and only recurse if an object is a class and it's not in the set.

```
HashSet<object> hashSet = new HashSet<object>();

public static T SetEmptyPropertiesNull<T>(T request)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        object value = property.GetValue(request, null);

        if (typeof(value).IsClass && !hashSet.Contains(value))
        {
            hashSet.Add(value);
            SetEmptyPropertiesNull(value);
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((value ?? string.Empty).ToString()))
            property.SetValue(request, null);
     }
     return request;
}
```